# Jsoup code not working

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Hi im really new to coding. Im trying to pull the text (HTML) from a specific website http://www.rfebs.es/estadisticas/2017/liga/B_res.php using jsoup but I can't seem to do it. Here is my code, thank you in advance!

```
package davidgb.baseballspain;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView texx;
Document doc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    texx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textp);
    Button but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new doit().execute();
        }
    });
}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String words;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rfebs.es/estadisticas/2017/liga/B_res.php").get();
            words= doc.text();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        texx.setText(words);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your class so that you don't need to access common variable across different threads:

```
public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rfebs.es/estadisticas/2017/liga/B_res.php").get();
            return doc.text();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        texx.setText(result);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I re-ran exact same code on my emulator and it works like a charm. Attaching screenshot as proof. One note: make sure you have `INTERNET` enabled in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidGarciaBallester please provide debug logs. Without knowing what the exception is and where it happens it is impossible to guess what the problem is. I have used that pattern hundreds of times successfully. The exception is likely somewhere else.

Comment: @DavidGarciaBallester see my EDIT for proof that it is working; Make sure you have `INTERNET` permission enabled

Comment: Here are the logs, as I said im really new and I have no idea what might be wrong (the internet permission was enabled all along):
03/19 22:35:33: Launching app $ adb push /Users/davidgarciaballester/AndroidStudioProjects/BaseballSpain/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/davidgb.baseballspain $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/davidgb.baseballspain" pkg: /data/local/tmp/davidgb.baseballspain Success`

Comment: $ adb shell am start -n "davidgb.baseballspain/davidgb.baseballspain.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Connected to process 2082 on device Nexus_6P_Edited_API_23 [emulator-5554] I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) I/art: Late-enabling JIT I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/davidgb.baseballspain-2/lib/x86 I/InstantRun: Instant Run

Comment: Runtime started. Android package is davidgb.baseballspain, real application class is null. W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/davidgb.baseballspain-2/lib/x86 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

Comment: [ 03-19 22:36:09.085  2082: 2082 D/         ]
 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa0b5f00, tid 2082
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa27592e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS A/art: art/compiler/dex/mir_method_info.cc:104] Check failed: invoke_type == kVirtual (invoke_type=direct, kVirtual=virtual) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting... A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Aborting thread: A/art:

Comment: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xac2cd200 A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] | sysTid=2087 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb2b30930 A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=8 core=0 HZ=100 A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] | stack=0xb2a33000-0xb2a35000 stackSize=1018KB A/art:

Comment: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #00 pc 0058be72 /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+226) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #01 pc 00551abe /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) const+286) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #02 pc 00517795 /system/lib/libart.so

Comment: (art::Runtime::Abort()+979) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #03 pc 0014d9f3 /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1343) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #04 pc 00256e24 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::MirMethodLoweringInfo::Resolve(art::CompilerDriver*, art::DexCompilationUnit const*, art::MirMethodLoweringInfo*, unsigned int)+3828) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #05 pc 00237ada /system/lib/libart-compiler.so

Comment: (art::MIRGraph::DoCacheMethodLoweringInfo()+634) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #06 pc 0025fe11 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::CacheMethodLoweringInfo::Start(art::PassDataHolder*) const+31) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #07 pc 00260223 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::PassDriverMEOpts::ApplyPass(art::PassDataHolder*, art::Pass const*)+45) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #08 pc 001e150b

Comment: /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::PassDriverME::RunPass(art::Pass const*, bool)+1707) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #09 pc 001e3873 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::QuickCompiler::Compile(art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, _jobject*, art::DexFile const&) const+2835) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #10 pc 00281c3f /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::CompilerDriver::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem

Comment: const*, unsigned int, art::InvokeType, unsigned short, unsigned int, jobject*, art::DexFile const&, art::DexToDexCompilationLevel, bool)+3055) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #11 pc 00281fc8 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::CompilerDriver::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*)+660) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #12 pc 00294fc9 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so

Comment: (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*)+613) A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] native: #13 pc 003ce36f /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*)+69) Application terminated.

Comment: First of all, update your question instead of posting logs in comments; second, it seems like you have an issue with your emulator, not your program as it looks like your application fails to launch, not a function fails to work. You can try one of two things (or both) try running on actual device; try re-installing Android Studio and adding a brand-new emulator. It could be that your machine is not powerful enough to run it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I ran it on my phone and it worked!!!!! Thank you so much for your help!!! While we're at it, do you know of any way I could just parse some of the html, like maybe specific words or numbers and not all of it.

Comment: You can use JSOUP for HTML parsing. Please consider marking the question as closed or resolved.